# pointer bug in a void function makes a variable receive -nan

Tags: c, pointers, printf, scanf

This is a very simple program, it just calculate the area of a triangle using Heron's formula, but I wanted to over complicate things a bit, so I made some functions that have pointers as parameters, which, in this case, they pretty much work like c++ references.

It works like that : it takes 3 sides (a,b,c) and calculates the area. The only problem is, whenever I enter a, I receive as an output `-nan`, which I did not understand why this happened.

When this sort of thing happens, is easy to blame the pointers, although is more likely the `scanf` or `printf` functions aren't behaving well.

If anyone could please explain to me why this is happening and how I can fix things up, I would be much thankful.

My code is bellow :

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void CalculateSemiPerimeter(double a, double b, double c, double *result)
{
    *result = ((a+b+c)/2.0);    
}

void heron(double *semiPerimeter, double a, double b, double c, double *result) //note that semiPerimeter and result have the same adresses
{
    double sub1 = (*semiPerimeter - a);
    double sub2 = (*semiPerimeter - b);
    double sub3 = (*semiPerimeter - c);

    double mult = (*semiPerimeter*(sub1)*(sub2)*(sub3)); //this part may be wrong

    *result = mult;
}

int main()
{
    double a, b, c, result; 
    scanf("%lf, %lf, %lf", &a, &b, &c);

    CalculateSemiPerimeter(a,b,c, &result);
    heron(&result, a, b, c, &result);

    result = sqrt(result);

    printf("%.2lf", result);
}
```

and here's a example of an input :

```
>>5
```

which brings as output :

```
-nan
```

Comment: `a`, `b` & `c` are uninitialised, and the return code of `scanf()` is not checked... Anything is possible...

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Note that ```scanf``` expects the input to be of the form: ```5, 6, 7```.

Comment: If you enter a character sequence that doesn't match your `scanf` format string, it will simply leave some of the variables unset, since you forgot to check if it successfully received all three.  *Check the return value from* `scanf`.  If it isn't 3, give an error and exit, or prompt the user to try again.  Don't just give garbage results.

Comment: @HaveMercy, "whenever I enter a" --> Please post an exact example of input used and output received.

Comment: @Haris that was exactly what was going wrong with my code, I _simply_ did not noticed I putted those commas by mistakes... really unfortunate, thanks for the answer !

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica alright

Comment: @HaveMercy Detail: with input `"5\n"`, the `'\n'` does not match a `','` and so `scanf()` stops and returns 1 with only `a` assigned and `b, c` left with uninitialized values  ... and the resulting chaos ensues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least these issues:

**Unchecked input**

The return value of `scanf()` was unchecked.  If  `a,b,c` were successfully written, `scanf()` returns 3.

```
// scanf("%lf, %lf, %lf", &a, &b, &c);
if (scanf("%lf, %lf, %lf", &a, &b, &c) != 3) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Input failure.\n");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

This would happen if input was `"1 2 3"` as the format expects `"1,2,3"` - commas between the numbers.

Further, code should *sanitize* inputs, checking if any are negative.

**Advanced: Computational error**

With extreme values, say when `a` much greater than `b` and `b` much greater than `c`, `*semiPerimeter - a` may result in severe loss of precession or even a negative number leading to a later trouble with `sqrt(some_negative)`.

Instead code could be more careful and reduce computational errors.  Rather than form `sub1` with `(a + b + c)/2 - a`, use `(-a + b + c)/2`.  This reduces [cancellation error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation).

One level of improvement:

```
// Return the result and no need to pass in semiPerimeter.
// void heron(double *semiPerimeter, double a, double b, double c, double *result)
double heron(double a, double b, double c) {
  double semiPerimeter = (a + b + c)/2;
  double sub1 = (-a + b + c)/2;
  double sub2 = ( a - b + c)/2;
  double sub3 = ( a + b - c)/2;
  return semiPerimeter * sub1 * sub2 * sub3;
}
```

Still with pathological inputs (unreal triangle lengths), the return value of `heron()` may be negative.

```
result = heron(a, b, c);
if (result < 0.0) {
  ; // TBD code that reports error.
} else {
  result = sqrt(result);
  ...
}
```

2nd level of improvement:

Sort `a, b, c` by magnitude, greatest to least.
Change to below to further reduce cancelation error.

```
double sub3 = ( a + (b - c))/2;
```